# HTML5 audio element - seek slider - Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The provided double value is non-finite

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, web-audio-api

This is my first question on Stack Overflow; apologies if I have done it wrong.

I am attempting to use the Web Audio API to create a nice little audio player for myself. However, I have run into a problem in trying to create a "seek" function for a user to skip around in the song.

HTML:

```
<p>Seek Slider</p>
<input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var seekslider = $('#seekslider');

$(seekslider).mousedown(function(e) {
  seeking = true;
  seek(e);
});

$(seekslider).mousemove(function(e) {
  seek(e);
});

$(seekslider).mouseup(function(e) {
  seeking = false;
});

function seek(e) {
  if (seeking) {
    seekslider.value = e.clientX - seekslider.offsetLeft;
    console.log(typeof(seekslider.value));
    console.log(seekslider.value, audio.currentTime);
    seekto = audio.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
    console.log(seekto);
    audio.currentTime = seekto;
  }
}
```

The error:

> Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The provided double value is non-finite.

Now, `console.log(typeof(seekslider.value))` returns a number.
however, `console.log(seekslider.value)` returns `NaN`.

I understand the value of `currentTime` is a float with a decimal point.

I have attempted:

```
parseFloat(e.clientX - seekslider.offsetLeft);
```

In addition to numerous other attempts at solving this using `parseFloat`.

I am just a bit confused.  I sincerely appreciate any help y'all have to offer.  Good day folks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a jQuery problem, per se.

The issue is that a JQuery object doesn't have `offsetLeft`. Only actual DOM elements have that property.

So effectively what you're doing is `e.clientX - undefined`, which of course is `NaN`.

Comment: Hey, Kevin.  Thanks for that explanation, very clear.  Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem.  It appears that jQuery does not play well with the web audio API.

Changed
`var seekslider = $('#seekslider');` to

`var seekslider = document.getElementById('seekslider');`

Made the program work.  I will leave this up in case it trips up any other novice developers such as myself.

Answer (score 0):

isFinite() will resolve this error:

```
if (!isFinite(seekto)) {
    console.log(seekto);
    audio.currentTime = seekto;
}
```